# Can RStudio (Posit) reformat .tex file to add line returns when the cursor reaches the end of a line (predefined length)

Tags: latex, rstudio, editor

I'm using RStudio with `.tex` files. I took a `.tex` that I want to modify but found that the paragraphs are very long in the editor (see short example below). The 'problem' is that whenever I want to track changes with such a document, a small modification in a sentence highlights the whole paragraph.

So I'm looking for a way to reformat `.tex` files to have a line return within paragraph automatically (I have lots of `.tex` files and some of them have tables and figures.) Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=letter]{report}

\begin{document}

This is a very long paragraph. A paragraph (from Ancient  (parágraphos) 'to write beside') is a self-contained unit of discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. Though not required by the orthographic conventions of any language with a writing system, paragraphs are a conventional means of organizing extended segments of prose. (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph)
d aasd a
sd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asd  

\end{document}
```

I'm looking for something like this (added line returns manually):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=letter]{report}

\begin{document}

This is a very long paragraph. A paragraph (from Ancient  (parágraphos) 'to write beside') is a self-contained 
unit of discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. Though not required by the orthographic 
conventions of any language with a writing system, paragraphs are a conventional means of organizing extended 
segments of prose. (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph)
d aasd a
sd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd 
asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd 
asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd 
asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd 
asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd 
asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asdsd asd asd asd asd  

\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but perhaps WrapRmd RStudio 'Addin' might work here https://github.com/tjmahr/WrapRmd